# Potential divider problem

Tags: electric-circuits, electricity, electric-current, voltage

[image]

What does the curved arrow represent? The answer states that L1 will be dimmer than L2.

From my current knowledge, moving the contact K closer to X will somehow increase the voltage of L2 meaning it will glow brighter than that of L1 ( But how? ). In addition how does this circuit even work? How does the current flow through that curved arrow?

Answer (score 0):

The junction between L1 and L2 and k can be represented as the same point as they will have the same potential
And as resistance is directly proportional to length of the wire, decreasing the length of a wire results in decrease of resistance
When k is moved towards x, the length KX decreases resulting in decrease in resistance of the L1-R1 system that decreases the potential difference accross LQ resulting in dimming of L1[image]

Comment: Isn't the wire from the middle of the bulbs to point K both part of the L1-R1 and L2-R2 system, so how does the current flow through it? It seems like the current should go both up and down at the same time which is not possible.

Comment: In your simplified diagram how did you manage to split point K and add a line in the middle? Why can we do this?

Comment: Okay so the squiggly line is basically a conducting wire right?

Comment: So we can just arbitrarily vary it's length because it 's length doesn't change the way the circuit will behave, so if you just join both ends of K it won't affect the circuit
You can do it in any circuit diagram with conducting wires

Comment: An intuitive way to think how the current will behave through the squiggly wire: current will go through the system with least resistance.

Comment: Also i would refer you the wheatstone bridge, look it up on Google or if you know it already then you might understand the last comment a bit better